# React Native iOS simulator high CPU usage with TextInput callback functions with events

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I’m having a strange issue that I can’t make sense of. When I’m assigning callbacks to `TextInput` and try to get the event out of callback with an arrow function, the ios simulator starts using a lot of CPU as if in an infinite loop: the main thread isn’t blocked but I think the JS thread is. The CPU is constantly above %100 and doesn’t fall down unless I quit the app. I’ve written down the offending code below:

```
// LoginForm.js
render () {
  return <FormItem onFocus={this.onFocus} onBlur={this.onBlur} />
}
```

part of `FormItem` component’s render method renders like this:

```
// FormItem.js
render () {
  const { onFocus, onBlur } = this.props
  <FormInputRow
    ref={ref => (this.formInputRef = ref)}
    {...{
      onFocus,
      onBlur,
    }}
  />
}
```

and part of `FormInputRow` component’s render method is:

```
// FormInputRow.js
render () {
  const { onFocus, onBlur } = this.props
  return (
    <StyledTextInput
      innerRef={ref => (this.textInputRef = ref)}
      onFocus={onFocus}
      onBlur={onBlur}
    />
  )
}
```

in `LoginForm.js` there is no problem if `onFocus` and `onBlur` are defined this way:

```
// LoginForm.js
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this)
  this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this)
}

onFocus () {
  console.tron.log('Focus event')
}

onBlur () {
  console.tron.log('Blur event')
}
```

but if the functions are defined with `event` parameter, like so:

```
// LoginForm.js
constructor (props) {
  super(props)
  this.onFocus = this.onFocus.bind(this)
  this.onBlur = this.onBlur.bind(this)
}

onFocus (event) {
  console.log('Focus event')
  console.log(event)
}

onBlur (event) {
  console.log('Blur event')
  console.log(event)
}
```

The CPU goes above %100 the first time I focus the `TextInput`. What might be causing this?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @Ante no, I obliviated my need for the event parameter and used the methods without params

Comment: was your input wrapped in scrollView? in my case, if I remove it the problem disappears

Comment: @Ante I believe it was, yes! thanks for discovering the source of the problem!